# How to filter generated Swagger JSON (yaml)

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I have over 5k lines long swagger.json file describing hundreds of paths and objects. I want to generate a TypeScript client (using swagger-codegen) using only a part of the endpoints. I don't want the generated TypeScript application to contain classes or interfaces connected with unused part of the swagger.json

How to filter out only a part of the Swagger documentation, describing the specified group of paths (e.g. all paths starting with `/api/*`)? Especially I want the filtered JSON to not contain `definitions` for unused data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, we created [swagger-json-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-json-filter) – a command-line tool allowing filtering a Swagger documentation. It can be easily used along other commands in bash:

```
cat input.json | swagger-json-filter --include-paths="^\/api\/.*" > output.json
```

The tool is performing a logic needed to filter out undesired definitions (nested also) from the output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it, using task automation (grunt, gulp, shell, whatever).
Basically it could be a 3 steps task:

1. get the swagger.json (or call the swagger code-gen to get the json, with something like `java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-x.x.x.jar generate -i <URL>  -l swagger -o GeneratedCodeSwagger` )
2. remove the definitions/paths that you want to exclude and create a modified swagger.json
3. call the code-gen passing the modified json with `java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-x.x.x.jar generate -i GeneratedCodeSwagger\swagger.json -l typescript-angular`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This was the only idea I had about solving this issue. I've just wanted to be sure that there's no other way/tool that could be used to do that. So I'll try to write a simple command line tool in node.js.