# Swagger - filter the generation of API classes based on tags

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I'm using Swagger to generate the API starting from a swagger definition (yaml file).
I want to be able to filter which API classes should be generated by using the tags. For example, to generate only the API classes that have "tag1" but not "tag2".
Is there any solution to that ?
So I’m not interested in grouping them but in filtering.
I found a solution here [How to filter generated Swagger JSON (yaml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788099/how-to-filter-generated-swagger-json-yaml) but I want to know if i can filter them out directly by tags